# p:selectOneMenu list display

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have some problem with p:selectOneMenu. My selectOneMenu will populate a list with grouping. If the list is too long, the list get displayed upwards without any vertical scrollbar. It should display downwards with a vertical scrollbar.

If the selectOneMenu is populated with normal list without grouping, it works fine. List can display with a vertical scrollbar if its too long.

```xml
<p:selectOneMenu id="abcd_combo_box_ctpy2" styleClass="selectOneMenu">
    <f:selectItems value="#{pc_Abcd.carList2}" ></f:selectItems>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

```java
public List getCarList2() {

    List cars;

    SelectItemGroup g1 = new SelectItemGroup("German Cars");
    g1.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[] { 
            new SelectItem("BMW", "BMW"),
            new SelectItem("Mercedes", "Mercedes"),
            new SelectItem("Volkswagen", "Volkswagen"), 
            new SelectItem("Item 1", "Item 1"), 
            new SelectItem("Item 2", "Item 2"), 
            new SelectItem("Item 3", "Item 3"), 
            new SelectItem("Item 4", "Item 4"), 
            new SelectItem("Item 5", "Item 5"), 
            new SelectItem("Item 6", "Item 6"), 
            new SelectItem("Item 7", "Item 7"), 
            new SelectItem("Item 8", "Item 8"), 
            new SelectItem("Item 9", "Item 9"), 
            new SelectItem("Item 10", "Item 10"), 

    });

    SelectItemGroup g2 = new SelectItemGroup("American Cars");
    g2.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[] {
            new SelectItem("Chrysler", "Chrysler"),
            new SelectItem("GM", "GM"), 
            new SelectItem("Ford", "Ford"),
            new SelectItem("Item 21", "Item 21"), 
            new SelectItem("Item 22", "Item 22"), 
            new SelectItem("Item 23", "Item 23"), 
            new SelectItem("Item 24", "Item 24"), 
            new SelectItem("Item 25", "Item 25"), 
            new SelectItem("Item 26", "Item 26"), 
            new SelectItem("Item 27", "Item 27"), 
            new SelectItem("Item 28", "Item 28"), 
    });

    cars = new ArrayList();
    cars.add(g1);
    cars.add(g2);

    return cars;
}
```

Comment: Looks like PF issue :-S

Comment: Oh dear. Is there any workaround? I have been trying to google to find a workaround but did not managed to get anything.

Comment: I've been looking through [PF elite](http://www.primefaces.org/elite/) minor release fixes, seems they've not fixed this yet..

Comment: It is not always easy to workaround these kind of issues. Anyway, I would register an issue: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list Sooner or later, the issue will likely be resolved.

Comment: Thanks have register here. https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=6052&can=5&q=label%3AType-NewFeature&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 4):

Adjust the height of class "ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper".

Try this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
       xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      >
    <h:head>
    <style>

 .ui-selectonemenu-list,
 .ui-selectonemenu-panel,
 .ui-widget-content 
 {
  height:50% !important
   }


 .ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper
 {
  height:100% !important
   }


</style>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
<p:selectOneMenu id="abcd_combo_box_ctpy2" styleClass="selectOneMenu" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{pc_Abcd.carList2}" ></f:selectItems>
</p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I would want the height to be auto. I tried. It doesn't work too well. Reason I do not want to specify a fixed height is because sometime the items inside the selectOneMenu might be just 3 of them and if i set to say 200px, it doesn't look good.

Comment: I modified the code.
Try again.
With this styles, the list adjust height 50% space

Comment: What does this do...?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `styleClass="selectOneMenuGrouped"` in your `selectOneMenu` and following in `css`:

```
.selectOneMenuGrouped.ui-selectonemenu-list, .ui-selectonemenu-panel
 {
       max-height:50% !important;
       overflow: scroll; 
}


 .selectOneMenuGrouped .ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper
 {
       height:100% !important;
       overflow: scroll;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to get it working using this code (a little modofocation from above):

```
<style type="text/css">
   .ui-selectonemenu-list,
   .ui-selectonemenu-panel
   {
       max-height:50% !important;
       overflow: scroll;
   }
   .ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper
   {
       height:100% !important;
       overflow: scroll;
   }
</style>
```

Hope this helps solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following ensures that if you are using a filter (along with grouping), then the search bar stays at the top and only the items scroll.

```
    .ui-selectonemenu-list,
    .ui-selectonemenu-panel
    {
        max-height:50% !important;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    .ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper
    {

        overflow: auto !important;
    }
    .ui-selectonemenu-list {
        height:300px !important;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
```

The Html

```
      <p:selectOneMenu value="#{permissionController.selectedEntity}"
                             filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"
                             styleClass="selectOneMenu"
                             >
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{permissionController.entities}"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```